# Index of a pandas dataframe is currently a "group by" of two columns, but I want them as their own columns with a standard numerical index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, group-by

I have a dataframe df_stack with categories 'member_no', 'group', and 'color', which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIXcq.png)

My goal is to group by ('member_no', 'group') and list all colors that correspond to these pairs in their own column. My progress so far has been this:

```
dat = [[1, 'A', 'green'], [1, 'A', 'blue'], [1, 'B', 'red'], [2, 'A', 'blue'], [2, 'B', 'red'], [3, 'A', 'yellow'], [3, 'A','pink']]
cols = ['member_no', 'group', 'color']
df_stack = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=cols)

df2 = pd.pivot_table(df_stack, index= ['member_no','group'],columns=df_stack.groupby(['member_no','group']).cumcount().add(1),values=['color'],aggfunc='sum')
```

The resulting DF looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dit6c.png)

This is very close to what I'm required to do, but I ultimately need it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qi5j.png)

I'm confusing myself about how to turn the index into a standard [0,1,2,....] and making the member_no and group their own columns. Essentially I just want each pairing of (member_id, group) to have it's own row with the subsequent columns being all colors associated with that pairing. If one pairing has more than others, it's fine for the lesser pairing to have null values in those empty cells.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS Sorry I didn't post my dataframes as text instead of images, I haven't figured out how to do that yet :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `df2.reset_index()` at the end and check if that gives you what you need.

Comment: This did it! Thank you so so much